# How to write a tenantaware RepositoryItemReader in Spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-batch, multi-tenant

I have a job configured to run based on the job parameters and integrated with spring web and quartz to invoke based on demand and cron based. I am using RepositoryItemReader to take advantage of spring data. This is running as expected.

Now I want to introduce multi tenancy in the job. I have 3 tenants with different databases say tenant1, tenant2 and tenant3. Basically i want to run the batch job picking the data from the database based on the jobparameter. If the jobparameter is tenant1, i want to pick the data from the tenant1 database.

I have found an article on how to introduce multi tenancy in spring boot application here. https://www.baeldung.com/multitenancy-with-spring-data-jpa
The problem is that i am not able to understand where i could inject the context into the thread as i am using an AsyncTaskScheduler to launch a job and there are other jobs which are also registered in the context.

```
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("tenantId",tenantId)
                .addString("jobName",jobName)
                .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
        Job job = jobRegistry.getJob(jobName);
        JobExecution jobExecution = asyncJobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
```

My itemReader bean is described as

```
    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Person> itemReader() {
        return new RepositoryItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
                .name("ItemReader")
                .repository(personRepository)
                .arguments("personName").methodName("findByPersonNameEquals")
                .maxItemCount(30).pageSize(5)
                .sorts(Collections.singletonMap("createTs", Sort.Direction.ASC)).build();
    }
```

Comment: You added the `tenantId` as a job parameter. Where would this parameter be used in your reader?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine That is what i am unable to figure. Ideally i was looking to use this tenantId to set the context in the tenant to pick the correct database just like how it was mentioned in here https://www.baeldung.com/multitenancy-with-spring-data-jpa  but i couldnt think of exact place where i could do that

Comment: i could pass the tenantId parameter into the itemreader but the repositoryitemreaderbuilder creates a repositoryItemReader but the actual reading doesnt happen in the function right. So if could figure it where exactly the itemreader reads the data i could surround it setting the tenantId and clearing it later in the context. But seems like spring batch internally handles the reading.

Comment: Which approach from the article you shared are you planning to use? This is key to answer your question. For example, if you are going to use the database-per-tenant approach, you would configure multiple datasources in the application context and configure a step-scoped reader per database. My question was how this tenantId job parameter will be used in the reader? How would you do that without Spring Batch and Spring Data?

Comment: i was looking for database per tenant like in based on the tenant it should look in the database for that tenant.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue in our project when using the *RepositoryItemReader*. The reader could not access the tenant via a *ThreadLocal* with the default *TaskExecutor*.

To make the RepositoryItemReader access the *ThreadLocal*, I created a custom decorator *TaskExecutor* to provide the current main ***ThreadLocal***.
Ref: [https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskDecorator.html][1]

For example:

```
@Bean(name = "taskExecutorDecorator")
public TaskExecutor taskExecutorDecorator(ThreadPoolTaskExecutorBuilder taskExecutorBuilder) {
  taskExecutorBuilder = taskExecutorBuilder.taskDecorator(
          new TaskDecorator() {
            @Override
            public Runnable decorate(Runnable runnable) {
              String currentTenant = Tenant.get();
              return () -> {
                try {
                  Tenant.set(currentTenant);
                  runnable.run();
                } finally {
                  Tenant.remove();
                }
              };
            }
          });
  return taskExecutorBuilder.build();
}
```

Then provide the taskExecutor for a Step.

```
@Bean
public Step step(
      @Qualifier("taskExecutorDecorator") TaskExecutor taskExecutorDecorator, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
      ...) {
    return new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
        .<ClassA, ClassB>chunk(100, transactionManager)
        .taskExecutor(taskExecutorDecorator)
        ....
        .build();
}
```

Hope that it could help you.